# What's the best way to setup a master file with a bunch of subdomain pages?

Tags: php, html

I have a file called master.php, that has the following code that will pull the city and state from the subdomain and place it in the body.

```
$url = "//$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);
$subdomains = array_slice($host, 0, count($host) - 2 );
$location = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $subdomains[0] . ", " . $subdomains[1]));
```

Lets say my url is: http://grand-rapids.mi.rootdomain.com/.

In my master.php file I have the layout, stylesheets, etc. Then in the body, I have text like:

```
"We're servicing <?php echo $location; ?> please call us today."
```

What the end user sees is:

```
"We're servicing Grand Rapids, MI please call us today."
```

I would like to create several subdomains like:

- kentwood, mi
- grandville, mi

In each of these subdomain index files, I had put:

```
<?php include_once("master.php") ?>
```

hoping that my code would pull the subdomain url and place it in the text where I've placed

```
<?php echo $location; ?>
```

It doesn't echo the correct location. It keeps echoing the Grand Rapids, MI location.

I don't know if this is even possible or what I need to change to make this work. Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Huh? This made little sense.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize that stackoverflow had striped out some things. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: "It's not working" isn't enough information for anyone to help you.  What if you `var_dump($_SERVER)`, does that show anything on the subdomains?  What does work and what does not work?

Comment: I edited my response. 

On the kentwood.mi subdomain, it still shows grand rapids, mi. 

I think its because I'm for the kentwood.mi I'm using the include_once and pulling everything from the grand rapids subdomain. I just don't know the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I made my master.php a master.html then when I pulled the file in the new subdomains it changed my variables. Yay!